# MODX Revolution Wayfinder return empty line

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, wayfinder

I have some resources and I'm trying to show menu with wayfinder:

```
[[Wayfinder? &startId=`0` ]]
```

But wayfinder returns nothing. Resources are under the root and published.

What's wrong?

Comment: Need some more detail in order to help. What version of Revolution are you using? Where is the Wayfinder snippet call, in your template or a chunk or...? Are all the resources published, and the hide from menu checkbox is NOT selected? Have you cleared the cache? Anything in the error log?

Comment: MODX Revolution 2.4.0-pl.
In my template. Published, not hidden. No erros in log.

Comment: And Wayfinder is installed? (Revo doesn't install with Wayfinder already included the way it used to.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks LIannotti a lot!

Wayfinder should be installed (in package manager) and not included.